# Mystery definitions for Hasura Graphql query Operators

Tags: javascript, postgresql, heroku, graphql, hasura

I'm using a complex derived graphql query in which I want to get all entries between a min and max value. I'm using Hasura's graphql schema for the query.

Heroku's Hasura defines a set of operators for the AggregateObject on their docs page
https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/graphql-api/query.html#whereexp for aggregation

The operators are as follows.

_eq
_neq
_in
_nin
_gt
_lt
_gte
_lte

However, the Hasura docs don't define what these operators each do, and there are no definitions in the schema analyzer I have available.

Does anyone out there know what each of the following operators in the hasura generated schemas do? Do any of them do min and max?

Comment: You'll need `_gt` for min and `_lt` for max. - `_gte` for greater than or equal, `_lte` for less than equal (inclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equals, not equals, in, not in, greater than, less than, greater than or equal. The docs have some examples: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html